# SocialEngine 4 i want to allow editing for owner only

Tags: socialengine

An existing Project i'm currently working on is based on SocialEngine 4, and i have to extend a plugin to allow Members for creating new stuff/editing their own stuff. Right now i got it to let them make new entries. They're also able to edit globally.Now my Question is how to change that into more granular permissions. Since i didn't found any documentary about what is what in "**engine4_authorization_permissions**" it would be great if someone could explain that to me, since socialengineforum.com is offline.

greets

Jan

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look to permission use in group plugin.

<<<<

you can also use same permission in your plugin.